# CakePHP 2.1 Using $this->flash and custom layout

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.1

I am using $this->flash('message', '/', 3, 'myLayout'); in one of my controller actions to redirect the user after a successful action.
Now, myLayout.ctp gets rendered, but the message does not get displayed. How can I access the message from within the layout?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/sessions.html#creating-notification-messages):

> The $element parameter allows you to control which element (located in
>   /app/View/Elements) should be used to render the message in. In the
>   element the message is available as $message. First we set the flash
>   in our controller:

So, in your layout:

```
echo $message;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the fast answer. But when I do this, the redirection does not work anymore... ?!

Comment: Huh? There's no reason why it would break any existing code, all it does is spit out the message that's passed to it by the session helper...

Comment: Well.. weirdly, if I dont specify a custom layout, i.e. leave that parameter empty, the redirection works (i.e. a link gets displayed and after 3 seconds the new page gets loaded). If I specify one, the text just gets rendered in the specified layout, but not as a link.

Comment: Also found out, that <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3;url=/"> does not get set in the rendered layout - that might be the reason so I will insert it manually..